# Extracting fields from an emails based on values in a database as training set

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, named-entity-recognition

Ive got 480 emails and each of them consist of one or all of these values :-

[person, degree, working/not working, role]

So for example one of the email looks like this :-

```
    Hi Amy,

    I wanted to discuss about Bob. I can see that he has a degree in 
    Computer Science which he got three years ago but hes still unemployed. 
    I dont know whetehr he'll be fit for the role of junior programmer at 
    our institute.
    Will get back to you on this.

    Thanks
```

The corresponding database entry for this email looks like this

```
Email_123 | Bob | Computer Science | Unemployed | Junior Programmer
```

Now even though the data hasnt been labelled but we still have somewhat of a database to lookup which values were extracted into the 4 fields from each of the email.
Now my question is that how can I use this corpus of 480 emails to learn and extract these 4 fields using Machine Learning/NLP.
Do I need to manually tag all these 480 emails like..

```
I wanted to discuss about <person>Bob</person>. I can see that he has a degree in 
    <degree>Computer Science</degree> which he got....
```

Or is there a better way. Something like this (MarI/O - Machine Learning for Video Games) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qv6UVOQ0F44&t=149s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that each email has only one value for each field, and that the value is always reproduced verbatim from the email, you can use something like [WikiReading](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P/P16/P16-1145.pdf).

[image: WikiReading Extraction Example]

The problem is that WikiReading was trained on 4.7 *million* examples, so if you only have 480 that's nowhere near enough to train a good model.

What I would suggest is preprocessing your dataset to automatically add tags like in your example. Something like this, in pseudo-python:

```
entity = "Junior Programmer"
entity_type = "role"
mail = "...[text of email]..."

ind = mail.index(entity)
tagged = "{front}<{tag}>{ent}</{tag}>{back}".format(
  front=mail[0:ind],
  back=mail[ind+len(entity):],
  tag=entity_type,
  ent=entity)
```

You'll need to adjust for case issues, multiple matches, and so on.

With tagged data you can use a conventional NER system like a CRF. [Here](https://spacy.io/docs/usage/entity-recognition)'s a tutorial using spaCy in Python.

Comment: Thanks. Based on this pseudocode what would a tagged snippet look like for the eaxmple scentence from my question , ie. "I wanted to discuss about Bob. I can see that he has a degree in 
    Computer Science which he got three years ago but hes still unemployed. 
    I dont know whetehr he'll be fit for the role of junior programmer at 
    our institute."

Comment: It would look like your example with tags above, "I wanted to discuss about <person>Bob</person>. I can see that he has a degree in <degree>Computer Science</degree>" etc.